# Convergence of a series with divergent odd and even sub-term series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2 n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2 n+1}$ both diverge, then prove/disprove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}$ diverges as well.

Can we take the counters as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
Where $a_n=\left\{ \begin {array}{ll} \frac{1}{n}& n \textit{ is odd}\\ \frac{-1}{n}& n \textit{ is even}  \end{array} \right.$

Comment: This works but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n$ is an even more classic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works perfectly. You will want to be careful in proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ actually does converge - using the limit of the partial sums.